# windows phone 8 panorama titlebinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

i am not able to bind to the panorama title . any idea how? other binding are working perfectly.

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">
 <phone:Panorama x:Name="pnBookDetails">
 <phone:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
 <DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding BookTitle, Mode=OneWay}"  />
 </DataTemplate>
 </phone:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
```

.cs file

```
await bookdetailsvm.GetBookDetails(Convert.ToInt64(bookid));
ContentPanel.DataContext= bookdetailsvm.booksdetailsObject;  returns Books object
```

book object

```
 public class Books : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private long _BookId = 0;
    public long BookId
    {
        get
        {
            return _BookId;
        }
        set
        {
            _BookId = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("BookId");
        }
    }

    private string _ISBN = string.Empty;
    public string ISBN
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ISBN))
            {
                return "No ISBN found";
            }
            else
            {
                return _ISBN;

            }
        }
        set
        {
            _ISBN = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ISBN");
        }
    }

    private string _BookTitle = string.Empty;
    public string BookTitle
    {
        get
        {
            if (_BookTitle.Length > 35)
            {
              return _BookTitle.Substring(0, 35) + "...";
           }
            else
                return _BookTitle;
        }
        set
        {
            _BookTitle = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because the title is not binded.

The right syntax is:

```
<phone:Panorama x:Name="pnBookDetails" Title="{Binding BookTitle, Mode=OneWay}">
    <phone:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" />
    </DataTemplate>
 </phone:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems other people have had the same issue; maybe you could try without the TitleTemplate?

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/wpapps/en-US/7ddbc4d9-a7e4-40f0-8912-e0aa7e512996/panorama-title-template-binding-issue

or

[Panorama Image Title (bind image path)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188124/panorama-image-title-bind-image-path)